# Can the vim tagbar display a local variable?

Tags: vim, ctags, tagbar

[image: The image shows that global variable Class A, but the local variable can't be show in tagbar,why? I want tagbar show local variable str,m,n and how to set??]
The image shows that global variable Class A, but the local variable can't be show in tagbar,why? I want tagbar show local variable str,m,n and how to set??

Answer (score 8):

What gets parsed by *ctags* depends on the language; based on the screenshot, you're interested in C/C++, where it doesn't do this. I don't know the original reasons, but I guess:

- With huge code bases (and who hasn't?), you (and maybe also the editor) would be overwhelmed by the number of tags. Remember that *tagbar* is kind of special in that it only shows the tags for the current file; usually the tags database is for an entire project.
- It's good practice to keep individual functions short and small; who needs tags lookup when ideally each function fits onto the screen in its entirety?!

The *Exuberant Ctags* parser can be extended with custom language definitions based on regular expressions (see the `--langdef=<language>` and `--regex-<language>` arguments). If you can come up with a good pattern for local variables, you could have them parsed.

Answer (score 3):

Exuberant Ctags has support for local variables as tags, they're just turned off by default.  I'd imagine they'd make your tags file huge for a project of any significant size, and I've never turned them on for just that reason (my tags files are already many megabytes).  But if you want to give them a try, just add `--c++-kinds=+l` (assuming c++) to your `ctags` command when you generate the tags file and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

first, tagbar show all tags from ctags and ctags default do not deal with function prototypes, external variable, and *local variables* (try this in shell: ctags --list-kinds=c++); 
second, tagbar's tagbar_type_cpp variable use for this:

```
let g:tagbar_type_cpp = {
    \ 'kinds' : [
        \ 'd:macros:1',
        \ 'g:enums',
        \ 't:typedefs:0:0',
        \ 'e:enumerators:0:0',
        \ 'n:namespaces',
        \ 'c:classes',
        \ 's:structs',
        \ 'u:unions',
        \ 'f:functions',
        \ 'm:members:0:0',
        \ 'v:global:0:0',
        \ 'x:external:0:0',
        \ 'l:local:0:0'
    \ ]
\ }
```

Look at the last two lines.

that's all.